# R : ggplot - use geom_raster with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, geom-raster

Consider these 3 variables : `A` [100*1], `B` [100*1], and `M` [100*1]. Variable `M` has 7 classes. For each class, I would like to plot a `raster` like :

```
ggplot(data = test, aes(x = factor(A), y = factor(B), fill = M)) +
       xlab("A") + ylab("B") +
       geom_raster()
```

So, for each class, I can do it properly :

[image]

in the second step, I would like to plot all 7 classes as 7 subplots in one column using `facet_wrap` function. So, I generated a `data.frame` where I `rbind` `A`, `B`, and `M` of each class. I added a column to the `data.frame` as the `ID` of each class. the data frame `df` looks like this (I removed intermediate rows of each class to keep the data frame short) :

```
row A   B   M   ID
1   50  5   0.272727272727273   1
2   50  10  0.352941176470588   1
97  2000    200 0.75    1
98  2000    300 0.692307692307692   1
99  2000    500 0.692307692307692   1
100 2000    1000    0.444444444444444   1
1   50  5   0.199117609627896   2
2   50  10  0.176712023248457   2
98  2000    300 0.059602649006623   2
99  2000    500 0.101954497349775   2
100 2000    1000    0.12773219045144    2
1   50  5   0.864866760389603   3
2   50  10  0.88297043479882    3
3   50  20  0.904572710950147   3
98  2000    300 0.96047443246472    3
99  2000    500 0.96047443246472    3
100 2000    1000    0.925079933067989   3
1   50  5   1   4
2   50  10  1   4
96  2000    150 1   4
97  2000    200 1   4
98  2000    300 1   4
99  2000    500 1   4
100 2000    1000    1   4
1   50  5   0.907284768211923   5
2   50  10  0.921192052980132   5
3   50  20  0.942384105960265   5
98  2000    300 0.987417218543044   5
99  2000    500 0.974172185430469   5
100 2000    1000    0.951655629139076   5
1   50  5   6.875   6
2   50  10  6.75    6
3   50  20  6.5 6
97  2000    200 0   6
98  2000    300 -0.625  6
99  2000    500 -6.375  6
100 2000    1000    -7  6
1   50  5   -489.141    7
2   50  10  -446.8695   7
3   50  20  -335.402    7
4   50  50  -208.469    7
96  2000    150 3.492   7
97  2000    200 7.056   7
98  2000    300 11.177  7
99  2000    500 12.827  7
100 2000    1000    14.487  7
```

To plot the 7 rasters I used this :

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(A), y = factor(B), fill = M)) +
          xlab("A") + ylab("B") +
          geom_raster() + 
          facet_wrap(~ID, ncol = 1)
```

What it plots, looks like this :

[image]

that is not correct. It seems it considers all 7 `facets` as one `ratser`. I could not find the problem. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that it considers the facets as one raster. If you print or save the image out larger, you'll be able to see each facet more clearly

Comment: No, the first three are all black. It is not the matter of size of the image. since in fact, M varies between different ranges for different ID.

Comment: @Reyhaneh You have already noted in your own comment that M varies between different ranges. In your first plot, the range of fill values is somewhere in the region of `0.4, 1`. In your second plot, the range of fill values is around (-400, 0)--with that scale, a range of values in `0.4, 1` *would* be indistinguishably black. Do you want a separate scale for each facet?

Comment: Yes, exactly that’s what I want. How can i do so ?

Comment: If you want a different M scale for each facet, it might be best to plot each ID raster seperately, convert them to grobs with `ggplotGrob()`, after which you `rbind(..., size = "last)` them. You can suppress the x-axis labels, text and titles in `theme()` for the first 6 plots. The alternative is to rescale the M values for each ID to a common range.

Comment: thanks, would you please post your solution as an answer?